# brace-inititialisation of boost::json::value converts it from an object to an array

Tags: c++, json, boost

In the below example I parse a json object using `boost::json`.

When I print the type of the returned `boost::json::value` it is of type `object`, as expected.

I then have 2 classes which are identical in every way, other than in `BraceInit` I initialise my member `boost::json::value` using brace initialisation and in `ParenInit` I initialise my member `boost::json::value` using parens.

Using brace initialisation causes my `object` to be converted into an `array`, of size 1, containing my original `object`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/json.hpp>

namespace json = boost::json;

void print_type(const json::value& jv)
{
    switch (jv.kind())
    {
        case json::kind::object: std::cout << "object\n"; break;
        case json::kind::array: std::cout << "array\n"; break;
        default: std::cout << "other\n"; break;
    }
};

struct BraceInit
{
    BraceInit(json::value jv)
        : _jv{jv}
    {
        print_type(_jv);
    }
    json::value _jv;
};

struct ParenInit
{
    ParenInit(json::value jv)
        : _jv(jv)
    {
        print_type(_jv);
    }

    json::value _jv;
};

int main()
{
    const std::string str = R"({ "foo": "bar" })";
    const json::value jv = json::parse(str);
    print_type(jv);

    BraceInit b(jv);
    ParenInit p(jv);
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

> ```
> object
> array
> object
> ```

What is happening here?

Is my "brace initialisation" actually not doing brace initialisation as I expect, but rather creating an `std::initializer_list` of size 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `[class.base.init]/7`

> The expression-list or braced-init-list in a mem-initializer is used to initialize the designated subobject (or, in
> the case of a delegating constructor, the complete class object) according to the initialization rules of 11.6 for
> direct-initialization.

11.6 here refers to `[dcl.init]`, which, under paragraph 17 states:

> The semantics of initializers are as follows. The destination type is the type of the object or reference being
> initialized and the source type is the type of the initializer expression. If the initializer is not a single (possibly
> parenthesized) expression, the source type is not defined.
>
> (17.1) — If the initializer is a (non-parenthesized) braced-init-list or is = braced-init-list, the object or reference is
> list-initialized (11.6.4).

11.6.4 simply refers to `[dcl.init.list]`.

So, to me, it sounds like `_jv{jv}` calls the initialization-list version of the constructor (if it exists), which, according to the [boost documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/json/doc/html/json/dom/initializer_lists.html), produces an array.

Note: all items from C++17 draft N4659

You can see this in a simplified version here: https://godbolt.org/z/9qrf3EooY

---

Edit: [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) simplifies this to:

> A std::initializer_list object is automatically constructed when:
>
> a braced-init-list is used to list-initialize an object, where the corresponding constructor accepts an std::initializer_list parameter

Comment: Thanks, the cppreference edit really does clarify it

Comment: Nice explanation. I still cannot understand why initialization in C++ has to be such a mess. A similar pitfall is `std::vector<int> v{2}` vs. `std::vector<int> v(2)`.