# vector move operation vs element move operation

Tags: c++

For the following example, why the vector move operation is not triggered? How do I know when I should explicitly use a move operator?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector> 

using namespace std;

class Test {
  public: 
    Test() {
      std::cout << " default " << std::endl;
        
    }
    
    Test(const Test& o) {
        std::cout << " copy ctor " << std::endl;
    }
    
    Test& operator=(const Test& o) {
        std::cout << " copy assign " << std::endl;
        return *this;
    }
    
    Test(Test&& o) {
        std::cout << " move ctor" << std::endl;
    }
    
    Test& operator=(Test&& o) {
        std::cout << " move assign " << std::endl;
        return *this;
    }
};

int main()
{
  std::cout << " vector: " << std::endl;
  std::vector<Test> p;
  p = {Test()}; // expect vector move here since the RHS is temporary. 
  std::cout << std::endl;
   
  std::cout << " single value " << std::endl;
  Test tt;
  tt = Test();
}
```

Output:

```
 vector: 
 default 
 copy ctor 

 single value 
 default 
 default 
 move assign
```

I was under the impression that when we assign a temporary variable to a lvalue (the single value case in the example), it would trigger a move operation if it exists. Seems that I was wrong and my understanding was overly simplified, I need to carefully check case by case to ensure there's no redundant copy.

Comment: Remember what I said in your last question about the `vector` prizing consistency over speed and not using the `move` operator unless you promised that it was safe?

Comment: Recommend explicitly stating in the question where you expect the move.

Comment: I think that is because when you put the `Test()` inside the curly braces, it create an `std::initialization_list<std::vector>`, and then it copies the init-list into the vector, and copy each `Test` (in this case your single `Test` instance) into the vector. Does the vector constructor know to move the values instead of copying?

Comment: `p = {Test()};` uses the `operator=( initialization_list )` variant, not `operator=( vector&& )`. See the answer in the linked question. The answer in it should clarify what the standard says when using the `{...}`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [brace-inititialisation of boost::json::value converts it from an object to an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72175652/brace-inititialisation-of-boostjsonvalue-converts-it-from-an-object-to-an-ar)

Comment: *"why the vector move operation is not triggered?"* -- what evidence do you have that the move operation is not triggered? (One reason moving a vector is efficient is that moving a vector does not move elements contained in the vector, so your current output is inconclusive regarding this move.) You could be right about the lack of a vector move, but at the same time, your question lacks evidence one way or the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::vector` has an [assignment operator](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/operator=/) that takes an `std::initializer_list`:

```
vector& operator= (initializer_list<value_type> il);
```

So when you wrote `p = {Test()};` you're actually using the above assignment operator.

Now why a call to the copy constructor is made can be understood from [dcl.init.list](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/dcl.init.list), which states:

> An object of type `std::initializer_list<E>` is constructed from an initializer list as if the implementation allocated a temporary array of `N` elements of type `const E`, where `N` is the number of elements in the initializer list. **Each element of that array is copy-initialized with the corresponding element of the initializer list**, and the std::initializer_list object is constructed to refer to that array.